# ajax request to get json response in php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use ajax to get response from json_encode.How do I do this?I am new to AJAX.

```
  $sip[$key] = array(
      'user'=>$user,
      'status'=> $status,
  );

  }

  json_encode(array('online' => $sip));`
```

Comment: You have to print it `print json_encode(array('online' => $sip));`

Comment: Please specify clearly what you want to achieve??

Comment: {"online":[{"user":"1004","status":"Unmonitored"},{"user":"1005","status":"online"},{"user":"1006","status":"Unmonitored"},{"user":"2501","status":"Unmonitored"},{"user":"2502","status":"online"},{"user":"2503","status":"Unmonitored"},{"user":"2504","status":"Unmonitored"}]}

Comment: I got respose like this.I want to display use and its status in table.Using ajax request

Answer (score 1):

On PHP side

```
$sip[$key] = array(
      'user'=>$user,
      'status'=> $status,
  );

  }

  $strArray = json_encode(array('online' => $sip));
  echo strArray;
  exit;
```

Use jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "URL TO BE  POST",
            data: "PARAMS",
            beforeSend: function () {


            },
            success: function (data) {

                var res = eval(data);
               console.log(res);


            }
        });
```

Comment: If there is any post variable you can set it in data.

Comment: var res = eval(data);
var x = 0;
var strObj = '';
for (x in res.online) {
   strObj = res.arrProceeds[x]['user'];
   console.log(strObj);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP :

$array =  array(
      'user'=>$user,
      'status'=> $status,
  );

echo json_encode($array);

Ajax:

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url :"/test.php",
   data:{"data":1},
   success:function(response){
    res = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(res.user);
  }  
})
```